# How to group entities that have the same subset of rows in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tables **Orders (Id)**, **Lot(Id, Name)** and **OrdersLot (IdOrder, IdLot)**. An order can accept multiple lots, and the many to many relationship is done with the OrdersLot table. How can I group the Orders that share the same exact lots?

Data Example:

| IdOrder |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |

| IdLot |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |

| IdOrder | IdLot |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | A |
| 3 | B |

Based on this data, I would need to generate a unique value that is the same for Order 1 and 3 (since they both have lot A and B), and different for Order 2.

The reason is that the logic I need to extend have a while loop that groups the orders by same properties, and then cycle in a while loop each OrderGroup doing queries only on the orders having those properties.

Any suggestions?

An option I considered is removing the OrdersLot table and saving a string with all the lots name in the Order table, but this definitely doesn't seem like the most performant way.

Maybe the solution could be generating a unique value for each subset of lot (using their ids for example)?

Comment: Sample data and desired results (as text) would be more helpful

Comment: What do you mean by "group the orders"?

Comment: Sorry about that, I added some more info, i hope it's clear enough. 

With group i mean that i need to save the grouped values in a temporary table where i save just the distinct values of each OrderGroup properties (there are more than just the lot). Maybe it could be simplified in how to generate a unique value from a list of Ids, so that each combination of lots have a different value.

Comment: You can use STRING_AGG to create a string of lot_ids which can then be used to group together orders for further processing

Comment: Please post what you have tried (SQL and your one challenge with that - as well as some sample data/table - and please update with WHICH sql engine with new tags for that

Comment: *"i would need to generate a unique value that is the same for Order 1 and 2 (since they both have lot A and B), and different for Order 2."" So you need to generate 2 values for order 2? What about order 3?

Comment: I'm guessing "same for Order 1 and 2" is a type and should be "same for Order 1 and 3".

Comment: @TN yes sorry that was a typo. Corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use STRING_AGG() to build up an ordered list of Lot IDs for each Order ID. The DENSE_RANK() function can then be used to assign distinct group IDs for each set of matching orders.

Something like:

```
SELECT
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY LotIdList) AS OrderGroupId,
    A.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        OL.IdOrder,
        STRING_AGG(OL.IdLot, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY OL.IdLot) AS LotIdList
    FROM OrdersLot OL
    GROUP BY OL.IdOrder
) A
ORDER BY OrderGroupId, A.IdOrder
```

Sample results:

| OrderGroupId | IdOrder | LotIdList |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A,B |
| 1 | 3 | A,B |
| 2 | 2 | B,C |

Alternately, you can just group by the constructed list as part of a larger query:

```
SELECT
    A.LotIdList,
    COUNT(*) AS OrderCount,
    STRING_AGG(A.IdOrder, ',') AS OrderIdList
FROM (
    SELECT
        OL.IdOrder,
        STRING_AGG(OL.IdLot, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY OL.IdLot) AS LotIdList
    FROM OrdersLot OL
    GROUP BY OL.IdOrder
) A
GROUP BY A.LotIdList
ORDER BY A.LotIdList
```

Results:

| LotIdList | OrderCount | OrderIdList |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A,B | 2 | 1,3 |
| B,C | 1 | 2 |

See [This DB<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/8_dLa6wk) for a demo. (Updated for recently posted sample data.)

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a unique value for sets that look the same, I'd be tempted to just create that from the unique set of values. If they're integer keys, then they're unique, and you could do something as simple as `string_agg`ing them together. Despite SQL being all about sets, doing set equivalence stuff like this is kind of a challenge.

Here's what I'd do. I created some junk data below. The first two queries are guaranteed to make some duplicates there. The last set is guaranteed to not.

The statement with the `string_agg` is the one your after.

```
drop table if exists #Orders
create table #Orders
(
    OrderID int
)

insert into #Orders (OrderID)
select top 10 row_number() over (order by (select null))
from sys.all_objects

drop table if exists #Lot
create table #Lot
(
    LotId int,
    Name nvarchar(128)
)

insert into #Lot (LotID, Name)
select top 20 row_number() over (order by (select null)), newid()
from sys.all_objects

drop table if exists #LotOrders
create table #LotOrders
(
    OrderLotID int identity(1,1),
    OrderId int,
    LotID int
)

insert into #LotOrders
(
    OrderId,
    LotID
)
-- Some guaranteed identical sets
select
    o.OrderId,
    l.LotID
from #Orders o
inner join #Lot l
    on l.LotID < 4
where o.OrderID < 3
union all
select
    o.OrderId,
    l.LotID
from #Orders o
inner join #Lot l
    on l.LotID < 6
where o.OrderID between 3 and 5
union all
-- Some unique sets
select
    o.OrderId,
    l.LotId
from #Orders o
inner join #Lot l
    on l.LotId % 9 = o.OrderID
where o.OrderID > 5
order by o.OrderID

select OrderID, GroupId = string_agg(LotId, '|') within group (order by LotId)
from #LotOrders
group by OrderId
order by GroupId
```